# Closed form for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

We know the closed form for Fibonacci number as $F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left[\left(1+\frac{\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n−\left(1−\frac{\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n\right]$

But while finding $F_n \pmod{99991}$ the closed form changes to

$$F_n= \frac{a^n -b^n}{a-b} \pmod{99991}  $$
where $a=55048$, $b=44944$.

How exactly we obtain the $a$ and $b$ values for some $m$?

Comment: [MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial for the Fibonacci recursion is $x^2-x-1$. If we are over some field $F$ with characteristic $\ne2$, we need to determine an extension field $K$ such that the polynomial splits. If $a$ and $b$ are roots, then the Fibonacci sequence can be written
$$
f_n=ua^n+vb^n
$$
and from $f_0=0$, $f_1=1$ we get $v=-u$, $u=1/(a-b)$. So the general form is
$$
f_n=\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}
$$
The roots are distinct whenever the characteristic of the field is $\ne5$.

In the case when $F$ is $\mathbb{Z}/99991\mathbb{Z}$ we find that the roots are in the field, so no extension is necessary, and they are $44944$ and $55048$. So
$$
f_n=22019(55048^n-44944^n)\bmod 99991
$$
because $22019$ is the inverse of $55048-44944$ modulo $99991$.

(Note: I used Pari-GP to make the computation, it's just very tedious to compute the roots by hand.)

Comment: How did you get the characteristic polynomial for Fn(mod 99991)?

Comment: @DurgaprasadGatti The characteristic polynomial is *always* $x^2-x-1$. For computing the roots you have to find the square roots of $5$ modulo $99991$, which are $10104$ and $89887$, then use the quadratic formula.

Comment: I don't get how to find √5 modulo 99991 ?

Comment: @DurgaprasadGatti Be *very* patient.

Comment: I am done being patient.. And found out how to get √5 modulo 99991.. and  I also found out √5 modulo (10^9+7)..btw The real challenge from the contest question is not this.